# Running subprocess with spaces in options in python

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess

I tried to search for an answer for a while, but I did not find anything so far for my specific case. I want to run command in python:

```
ssh -o ConnectTimeout=3 -o ProxyCommand="ssh -q -W %h:%p bastion.host.com" host.com  "screen -dmS TEST /bin/bash --login -c 'yes | script.sh --option-1 value1 -option2 value2 2>&1 | tee output.log'"
```

this is my code:

```
import subprocess

server_command = "screen -dmS TEST /bin/bash --login -c 'yes | script.sh --option-1 value1 -option2 value2 2>&1 | tee output.log'"
command = ['ssh', '-o', 'ConnectTimeout=3', 'ProxyCommand="ssh -q -W %h:%p bastion.host.com"', 'host.com', server_command]
    
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=None, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate(input=None)
```

Everything was working (screen was spawned with script running) until I added option with spaces: *ProxyCommand="ssh -q -W %h:%p bastion.host.com"*.

After that I get error:

```
>>> print(stderr)
b'ssh: Could not resolve hostname ProxyCommand="ssh -q -W %h:%p bastion.host.com": Name or service not known\r\n'
```

How can I please pass this option to my command?

Comment: "Everything was working until..." Please [edit] your question to describe what is happening with that change. Include whatever errors or exceptions that you're getting.

Comment: You're adding _literal_ quotes where in the original shell command they were _syntactic_. Just take them out.

Comment: That is to say: In bash (or any other POSIX shell), there's **no difference whatsoever** between `ProxyCommand="ssh -q -W %h:%p bastion.host.com"` and `"ProxyCommand=ssh -q -W %h:%p bastion.host.com"` or `'ProxyCommand=ssh -q -W %h:%p bastion.host.com'` -- they're all passed to ssh as exactly the same C string; the application has no way of even knowing that there was a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SSH command contains invalid arguments: `ProxyCommand` is an *option*, so it needs to be preceded by `-o`, same as `ConnectTimeout` (and, as noted by Charles Duffy, the redundant quotes inside that option string need to be removed, since the command is not passed to the shell):

```
server_command = 'screen -dmS TEST /bin/bash --login -c \'yes | script.sh --option-1 value1 -option2 value2 2>&1 | tee output.log\''
command = ['ssh', '-o', 'ConnectTimeout=3', '-o', 'ProxyCommand=ssh -q -W %h:%p bastion.host.com', 'host.com', server_command]
```

In general when your command line contains spaces and/or quotes and is passed to *another command*, it may be necessary to shell-quote it. The Python function [`shlex.quote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote) automates this. In your case it’s not necessary because you (correctly) manually quoted the command you’re passing to `screen` inside `server_command`. Alternatively you could have written the following:

```
script_command = 'yes | script.sh --option-1 value1 -option2 value2 2>&1 | tee output.log'
server_command = f'screen -dmS TEST /bin/bash --login -c {shlex.quote(script_command)}'
```

— Note the absence of manual quotes inside the shell command line. The advantage over manual quoting is that this will also work with nested levels of shell quoting, e.g. when nesting command invocations.

Comment: Thank you for reply. String instead of list was another error which I did after I started trying everything. I fixed it and updated the question with more info what is happening (shlex.quote did not help :( )

Comment: @rainmaker Ah yes, of course. I should have spotted that — see updated answer.

Comment: Does this code actually work? When I run `ssh -o 'ProxyCommand="ssh -q -W %h:%p a-host-i-can-access"' another-host-i-can-access` -- with literal rather than syntactic quotes, like the ones your Python code here is creating -- I get the error I would expect: `/bin/sh: exec: ssh -q -W a-host-i-can-access:22 another-host-i-can-access: not found`

Comment: ...which is to say, I'm really quite sure that keeping the quotes from the OP's original shell command -- in which they were treated as shell syntax -- and copying them into your Python code, where they're treated as literal, is the Wrong Thing.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy No, your comment/answer is spot on; I missed these quotes. This reinforces my conviction that shell quoting should never be done manually.